# Castelnuovo- Mumford regularity properties

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals

Let $R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be a graded ring and $S,T,U$ be monomials ideals.
$reg(S)=max\{j-i \backslash \beta_{i,j}(S) \neq 0\}$.

Assume $S+T=U$

**prove \disprove :** $reg(S+T^2) \leq reg(U^2)$.

We can see  $reg(S+T^2) \leq reg(S)+reg(T^2)-1 < reg(S)+reg(T^2)$ by [By Herzog result, see Corollary 3.2](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0512021v1.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example is due to Aldo Conca:

$R = k[x_1,x_2,x_3], S = (x_1^3x_2,x_1x_2^3,x_2^4,x_1^2x_2^2x_3^5), T = (x_1^4), U = S+T$. Then $\text{reg} (S+T^2) = 9$, while $\text{reg} U^2 = 8$.

Comment: It's unpublished. I'm not sure about the squarefree case.